# Are questions related to combat techniques on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

We have seen different combat techniques in our epic stories like Ramayana and Mahabharata. So, are Hinduism related combat techniques on-topic?

Some of the Combat techniques are:

- Archery (*It is ancient and practiced by many famous people like Lord Ram himself*)
- Hanuman combat (*It is said that Lord Hanuman used to fight in a unique way which still exists in Thailand*)
- Kusthi (*Lord Krishna kills Kamsa by challenging kusthi*)
- Sword fighting (*I forgot the name, but this technique is still popular in Kerala*)

Comment: U have provided good examples of those technique which are totally valid. So why would one flag it as off topic?

Comment: @TheDictator I am providing so that we can have a clear idea on what should be on-topic and what not. :)

Comment: I guess that wont be an off topic kind of question...

Comment: @TheDictator The guess should become sure. That is why I posted this question.

Comment: _Going to propose a new CombatTech site on Area51_...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions about what religious literature has to say about combat would certainly be on topic, e.g. "What technique did Krishna use to kill Kamsa?".

Questions about how to actually practice these combat techniques should not be. Questions about martial arts may be on-topic at [**Martial Arts**](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/).